# In Python how to make each line in a file to be a tuple and make them in a list?

Tags: python

We have a homework that I have a serious problem on.
The key is to make each line to a tuple and make these tuple to a list.
like `list=[tuple(line1),tuple(line2),tuple(line3),...]`.
Besides, there are many strings separated by commas, like `"aei","1433","lincoln",...`

Here is the question:

A book can be represented as a tuple of the author's lastName, the author's firstName, the title, date, and ISBN.

- Write a function, `readBook()`, that, given a comma-separated string containing this information, returns a tuple representing the book.
- Write a function, `readBooks()`, that, given the name of a text file containing one comma-separated line per book, uses `readBook()` to return a list of tuples, each of which describes one book.
- Write a function, `buildIndex()`, that, given a list of books as returned by `readBooks()`, builds a map from key word to book title. A key word is any word in a book's title, except "a", "an, or "the".

Here is my code:

```
RC=("Chann", "Robbbin", "Pride and Prejudice", "2013", "19960418")
RB=("Benjamin","Franklin","The Death of a Robin Thickle", "1725","4637284")
def readBook(lastName, firstName, booktitle, date, isbn):
    booktuple=(lastName, firstName, booktitle, date, isbn)
    return booktuple
# print readBook("Chen", "Robert", "Pride and Prejudice", "2013", "19960418")

def readBooks(file1):
    inputFile = open(file1, "r")
    lines = inputFile.readlines()
    book = (lines)
    inputFile.close()
    return book
print readBooks("book.txt")
BooklistR=[RC,RB]

def buildIndex(file2):
    inputFile= open("book.txt","r")
    Blist = inputFile.readlines()
    dictbooks={}
    for bookinfo in Blist:
        title=bookinfo[2].split()
        for infos in title:
            if infos.upper()=="A":
                title.remove(infos)
            elif infos.upper()=="THE":
                title.remove(infos)
            elif infos.upper()=="AN":
                title.remove(infos)
            else:
                pass
        dictbooks[tuple(title)]= bookinfo[2]
    return dictbooks
print buildIndex("book.txt")

#Queries#
def lookupKeyword(keywords):
    dictbooks=buildIndex(BooklistR)
    keys=dictbooks.viewkeys()
    values=dictbooks.viewvalues()
    for keybook in list(keys):
        for keyw in keywords:
            for keyk in keybook:
                if keyw== keyk:
                    printoo= dictbooks[keybook]
                else:
                    pass
    return printoo
print lookupKeyword("Robin")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  What is the problem with your code?  You should diagnose what problems you are running into, and where your code is running into problems.  It is helpful to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), including sample data (a couple of lines is fine) and your expected output.

Comment: Your code for `ReadBook` does not take a line (think 'string') and split it as requested; it takes the fields from a pre-split line and assembles them into a tuple.  Your function `ReadBooks` does not call `ReadBook` as the question requests.  Your function `BuildIndex` does not take the list of tuples generated by `ReadBooks`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with something like this?:

```
with open(someFile) as inputFile:
    myListofTuples = [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in inputFile.readlines()]
```

[Explanation added based on Robert's comment]

The first line opens the file in a `with` statement.  Python `with` statements are a fairly new feature and rather advanced. The set up a *context* in which code executes with certain guarantees about how clean-up and finalization code will be executed as the Python engine exits that context (whether by completing the work or encountering an un-handled exception).

You can read about the ugly details at: [Python Docs: Context Managers](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/context-managers.html) but the gist of it all is that we're opening *someFile* with a guarantee that it'll be closed properly after the execution of the code leaves that context (the suite of statements after the `with` statement.  That'll be done even if we encounter some error or if our code inside that suite raises some exception that we fail to catch.

In this case we use the `as` clause to give us a local name by which we can refer to the opened file object.  (The filename is just a string, passed as an argument to the `open()` built-in function ... the object returned by that function needs to have a name by which we can refer to it.  This is similar to who a `for i in whatever` statement binds each item in *whatever* to the name `i` for each iteration through the loop.

The suite of our `with` statement (that's the set of indented statements which is run within the context of the context manager) consists of a single statement ... a list comprehension which is bound to the name `myListofTuples`.

A list comprehension is another fairly advanced programming concept.  There are a number of very high level languages which implement them in various ways.  In the case of Python they date back to much earlier versions than the `with` statement --- I think they were introduced in the 2.2 or so timeframe.

Consequently, list comprehensions are fairly common in Python code while `with` statements are only slowly being adopted.

A list literal in Python looks like: `[something, another_thing, etc, ...]` a list comprehension is similar but replaces the list of item literals with an expression, a line of code, which evaluates into a list.  For example: `[x*x for x in range(100) if x % 2]` is a list comprehension which evaluates into a list of integers which are the squares of odd integers between 1 and 99.  (Notice the absence of commas in the list comprehension.  An expression takes the place of the comma delimited sequence which would have been used in a list literal).

In my example I'm using `for line in inputFile.readlines()` as the core of the expression and I'm splitting each of those on the common (`line.split(',')`) and then converting the resulting list into a `tuple()`.

This is just a very concise way of saying:

```
myListofTuples = list()
for line in inputfile.readlines():
    myListofTuples.append(line.split(','))
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much, my code finally works with your simple 2 lines though till now I don't know how you did it!

Answer (score 0):

One possible program:

```
import fileinput

def readBook(str):
    l = str.split(',')
    t = (l[0:5])
    return t

#b = readBook("First,Last,Title,2013,ISBN")
#print b

def readBooks(file):
    l = []
    for line in fileinput.input(file):
        t = readBook(line)
        # print t
        l.append(t)
    return l

books = readBooks("data")

#for t in books:
#    for f in t:
#        print f

def buildIndex(books):
    i = {}
    for b in books:
        for w in b[2].split():
            if w.lower() not in ('a', 'an', 'the'):
                if w not in i:
                    i[w] = []
                i[w].append(b[2])
    return i

index = buildIndex(books)

for w in sorted(index):
    print "Word: ", w
    for t in index[w]:
        print "Title: ", t
```

Sample data file (called "data" in the code):

```
Austen,Jane,Pride and Prejudice,1811,123456789012X
Austen,Jane,Sense and Sensibility,1813,21234567892
Rice-Burroughs,Edgar,Tarzan and the Apes,1911,302912341234X
```

Sample output:

```
Word:  Apes
Title:  Tarzan and the Apes
Word:  Prejudice
Title:  Pride and Prejudice
Word:  Pride
Title:  Pride and Prejudice
Word:  Sense
Title:  Sense and Sensibility
Word:  Sensibility
Title:  Sense and Sensibility
Word:  Tarzan
Title:  Tarzan and the Apes
Word:  and
Title:  Pride and Prejudice
Title:  Sense and Sensibility
Title:  Tarzan and the Apes
```

Note that the data format can't support book titles such as "The Lion, The Witch, and the Wardrobe" because of the embedded commas.  If the file was in CSV format with quotes around the strings, then it could manage that.

I'm not sure that's perfectly minimally Pythonic code (not at all sure), but it does seem to match the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your hardwork! But I cannot emulate your "import" syntax, the professor lets us only test on terminal, so maybe import doesn't work, but thanks anyway, you give me a nice and concise way of doing question3!!!!! Thank you very much!!!!